# Using QueryInterface on an IAudioSessionControl for ISimpleAudioVolume Fails to Compile

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

I have been driving myself mad with this problem for a few hours now. Essentially, I have begun development on a service that allows users to control audio volume for individual applications by sending packets over TCP to the server application. This is a hobbyist project to further my knowledge of C++.

I am using the ISessionEnumerator interface to build a list of pointers to the sessions. I would have thought it possible to control the volume directly from the sessions. I quickly figured out I would need another interface for this, suck as the ISimpleAudioVolume interface. I have the following code so far for retrieving the interface:

```
int AudioManager::AdjustVolumeBy(IAudioSessionControl * pSession, int adjustBy) {
    void * pVolumeControl;
    pSession->QueryInterface(IID_ISimpleAudioVolume, &pVolumeControl);
    return 0;
}
```

This produced the compilation error:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _IID_ISimpleAudioVolume
```

And I am including the following headers in my header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <audiopolicy.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <AudioSessionTypes.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <vector>
```

Additionally, when creating the project, I created it including ATL and MFC. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't set the _WIN32_WINNT and WINVER variables to Vista or later?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion here. Unfortunately, this didn't help fix the issue when I included this in the header file created by Visual Studio for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately managed to resolve this problem by adding "winmm.lib" to "Additional Dependencies" in Linker Input.

Additionally, for the reference of anyone else who may experience this issue, the original volume adjustment code was changed to:

```
int AudioManager::AdjustVolumeBy(IAudioSessionControl * pSession, float adjustBy) {
    ISimpleAudioVolume * pVolumeControl;
    float currentVolume;float newVolume;
    pSession->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ISimpleAudioVolume),(void**)&pVolumeControl);
    pVolumeControl->GetMasterVolume(&currentVolume);
    newVolume = currentVolume + adjustBy;
    if (newVolume < 0) {
        newVolume = 0;
    }
    pVolumeControl->SetMasterVolume(newVolume,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And I had to add:

```
allocationResult = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
```

To the class constructor to initialise the Component Object Model library for use.